# Operate on array elements without changing index

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to operate on certain elements of an array while referencing their index in the block. Operating on the whole array is easy

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
arr.each_with_index { |num, index| puts "#{num}, "#{index}" }
```

But what if I want to work just with elements `4`, `6` to return

```
4, 3

6, 5
```

I can create a new array composed of certain elements of the original and run the block on that, but then the index changes.

How can I select the elements and their index?

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a condition on it:

```
indice = [3, 5]
arr.each_with_index do
  |num, index| puts "#{num}, #{index}" if indice.include?(index)
end
```

This is another style:

```
indice = [3, 5]
arr.each_with_index do
  |num, index|
  next unless indice.include?(index)
  puts "#{num}, #{index}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from the question whether you are given values in the array and want to obtain their indices, or vice-versa. I therefore will suggest one method for each task. I will use this array for examples:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

**Values to Indices**

If you are given values:

```
vals = [4, 6]
```

you can retrieve the number-index pairs like this:

```
vals.map { |num| [num, arr.index(num)] }
  #=> [[4, 3], [6, 5]]
```

or print them directly:

```
vals.each { |num| puts "#{num}, #{arr.index(num)}" }
# 4, 3
# 6, 5
#=> [4, 6]
```

If an element of `vals` is not present in `arr`:

```
vals = [4, 99]
vals.map { |num| [num, arr.index(num)] }
  #=> [[4, 3], [99, nil]]
```

**Indices to Values**

If you are given indices:

```
indices = [3, 5]
```

you can retrieve the index-value pairs like this:

```
indices.zip(arr.values_at(*indices))
  #=> [[3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

and then print in whatever format you like.

If an index is out-of-range, `nil` will be returned:

```
indices.zip(arr.values_at(*[3, 99]))
  #=> [[3, 4], [5, nil]]
```

Comment: Yes!  I thought there had to be a solution like this. Thank you.

Comment: I think I need a more general solution. This works only if I know the value of the element in arr I want to work with. But what if a) I only know the position (e.g., I want to get the value of the element at index x).